# Загрузка видио из интернета

Tags: flash, html, javascript

Каким образом выгрузить видео с сервера? Возможно ли такое?
вот  [сам сайт](http://new.interneturok.ru/school/geometry/10-klass/parallelnost_pryamyh_i_ploskostej/parallelnye_pryamye_v_prostranstve_parallelnost_treh_pryamyh)

```
    <div class="player"/>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flash_video" name="flash_video" data="http://new.interneturok.ru/media/player/FlashMediaPlayer.swf" width="646" height="401"/>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FBF9E3">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="salign" value="ct">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="flashvars" value="xml_php=http://new.interneturok.ru/lessons&amp;id=1072&amp;category_id=1072&amp;begin=0&amp;player_mode=preset_player_1&amp;preloader=/media/player/preload.png&amp;widemode=false">
    </object>
    </div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что http://new.interneturok.ru/lessons используется, чтобы получить какие-то сведения от сервера. Возможно, правильно обратившись к нему можно получить XML с адресом видео и скачать это видео.

Comment: а не подскажите как туда правильно обратиться?